# "Sort Lines in Selection" for Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, sorting, plugins, applescript, textmate

I like Textmate's "Sort Lines in Selection" feature a lot. Is there something similar for Xcode 4? If not, what would be the best way to integrate such a feature (a plugin, Applescript, ...)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do this with Automator:

- Start Automator and select either:
  "Service" for macOS 10.7 or
  "New Document" followed by "Quick Action" for macOS 11
- Find and drag "Run Shell Script" into the workflow panel
- Select "Output replaces selected text"
- Type `sort -f` into the "Run Shell Script" textfield
- Save

Now you can sort lines in any textfield. Select some text and right-click or Control click and select the service you just created.

[image: Automator screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for this. Works good as a service in Xcode. But I added the ignore leading blank space option (sort -fb )  and got better results.

Comment: Very cool. For those who want to add the service as a keyboard shortcut: I seems that you have to go to System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Short Cuts -> Application Shortcuts, then in the "menu title" put the name of your service and assign a key.

Comment: For anyone having trouble with the Service not appearing in the Services menu, make sure that Automator is saving your file to the default location: `~/Library/Services`.

Comment: For anyone who hasn't used Automator before, the missing first 2 steps are 1. Open automator via spotlight and 2. Press New Document.

Comment: If you want to sort by a space delimited horizontal list example 1 3 2 , use a script with: xargs -n1 | sort -g | xargs

Answer (score 2):

After 4 years Xcode still doesn't have this feature builtin, but now it supports extensions. So here you go: "xcsort" is an extension to
[sort text in Xcode](http://apps.brrm.ru/xcsort/) 8. It adds a command to sort lines in selection.

Comment: FYI: xcsort was last updated in 2019 and no longer works with Xcode 12

Answer (score 2):

For macOS 10.14+ (Mojave) users who are looking at epatel's answer, Automator has renamed `Services` to `Quick Action`. I was lost for a moment until I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

**How**

In TextMate, open the bundle and see how they have implemented it ;)

Specifically, they have used `sort -f` for that command.

**In Xcode**

Xc4 doesn't offer external commands, but Xc3 did... what version are you using?

Here's an overview for Xc3's script system: http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.23/23.01/2301XCode/index.html

Xc4 allows you to run an external script via Behaviours, but you cannot pass or return text/selection.

**AppleScript**

You may be able to do it with AppleScript... every time I have tried to do anything nontrivial with AS + Xcode, it didn't work out very reliably (if at all). But that was with Xc3 - locating what you need may be easier with Xc4 (unified UI and all).

I just use TextMate for this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug on 10.7 and 10.8 where the shortcuts for Automator services don't always work until the services menu has been shown once from the menu bar. You can still select them from the context menu, but another option would be to assign a shortcut to a script like this:

```
try
    set old to the clipboard as record
end try
try
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using command down
    do shell script "export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8; pbpaste | sort -fn | pbcopy"
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down
    delay 0.05
end try
try
    set the clipboard to old
end try
```

Trying to get the clipboard when it's empty results in an error. pbpaste and pbcopy don't support Unicode by default in the environment used by do shell script.