# Refactor out explicit getters and setters in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, refactoring

I am currently refactoring some Objective-C code to remove the explicit getters and setters.

So this:

```
[instance member]
[instance setMember:value]
```

should become this:

```
instance.member
instance.member = value
```

Currently working on a regex for this, but if this has be solved already, I'd appreciate taking advantage of someone else's work.

Comment: Why? Is it desperately important style to you?

Comment: It is more verbose than necessary. It's code for a sample, that will get copy/pasted everywhere internally and externally.

Comment: The compiler has the information to do this, because it does the reverse when someone uses the dot syntax; likewise you would have to parse the property declaration in the general case, because the accessors can be renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have all your `[instance setMember:value];` calls translated to `instance.member = value;`, use Xcode's refactoring: ***Edit > Refactor > Convert to Modern Objective-C Syntax***. It will also convert the getters if applicable, like `variable = [instance member];` calls to `variable = instance.member;` syntax.

I might be misunderstanding your intention, but I'd like to point out that use of `instance.member;` is bad style *if you're not assigning the value to a variable*. If you're calling a method because of it's side-effects, use `[instance method];` instead to make the intention more clear. Use the dot-syntax only to actually read and write properties to avoid confusion.

Xcode 6.3 actually warns you if you've got a method/property that is returning a value and you're calling the getter without assigning it to a variable (like `viewController.view;` or `[viewController view];`) since it's assumed that this call is a mistake. To get rid of the warning you're getting, you need to explicitly tell the compiler that you are doing it for the side-effect (for example, to make sure the XIB is loaded) by casting to `void`, as in `(void)[viewController view];`.

To convert some setters the refactoring missed, you'll probably need to convert those by hand, I'm afraid. To find them, go to the *Find Navigator* (Cmd-3), select *Find > Regular Expression*. Use the regular expression `\[\[\w+\s+\w+\]\s+set` (unfortunately, you can't simply convert those calls using a regular expression since you would need to transform one character: `[foo setBar:123]` needs to be turned to `foo.bar = 123` which means the `B` would need to be turned to lower-case `b`). You could write a service for the context menu that does the necessary transformation (see the [top answer to *"Sort Lines in Selection" for Xcode 4*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8104750/400056) on how to write such as service) to speed up that manual task a bit.

Comment: Currently investigating. Your note about `(void)` as a prefix when pre-loading a viewController solved a warning already.

Comment: Hmmm...*Convert to Modern Objective-C Syntax* caught a few things, but did not catch everything I wanted. It passed over things like `[[self collider] setHidden:YES];`

Comment: Bummer. I've updated my answers with suggestions for this problem.